# User event Before Submit doesn't work in case of automatic PO creation (NETSUITE)

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to restrict the purchase order created automatically like when any dropship or special offer item selected in sales order?

Comment: You are going to need to add a lot more information to this question before anyone can give valuable advice.

Comment: Even though beforeSubmit is not triggered, afterSubmit is triggered. Maybe that helps.

Comment: HI Maria, thanks for your reply. after submit is triggered but in this case we dont want to save to record. Transactions are created many ways in Netsuite, For example, when a sales order is approved via Netsuite’s native approval process, the purchase order is automatically created. We need to make sure this blocking script will interact correctly and prevent the purchase order from being created.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm as of very recent discussions and testing with Netsuite that before submit does not trigger on automatically generated purchase orders.

We have an approvals system in place and were hoping purchase orders could be auto generated and stay pending supervisor approval but this is not possible as the before submit does not trigger.

An enhancement request has been raised by Netsuite for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks CraigyD for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of dropship and special order items is dependent on a checkbox. If you clear the checkbox when the order is approved then the automatic POs will not be created.

Checkbox clearing may be done by the user or may be done via a Before Submit user event script on the Sales Order.

If the need to restrict PO creation has something to do with PO vendor characteristics where you may also need to restrict general PO creation then you should extract the vendor check to a library file. that way it could be used in the SO beforeSubmit to clear the createpo flag and the PO beforeSubmit to throw an error.

You could also use the PO After Submit "specialorder" or "dropship" events to check the PO vendor after submit and delete the created PO.

However given your explanation in the comments the SO shouldn't be able to be approved. i.e. why take a drop ship order where the components are not orderable?

Comment: Hi bk, in our project in many places we are using nlapiCreateRecord('purchaseorder', {recordmode: 'dynamic'}); and nlapiSubmitRecord(). so if the vendor is blocked we need to restrict PO creation. we want to prevent PO creation using event but before submit is not working and aftersubmit is working but in this case PO  is created. IS there any way to restrict.

Comment: That’s a different question than your original question

Comment: hi BK,this is also the part of the issue.in both cases we need to restrict  PO created internally.